# CTE works but a simple JOIN will not?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to figure out why utilizing a CTE to strip out erroneous information works but I cannot use the same data transformation directly in the `JOIN`. So for instance, I have the following `DOCUMENT` table that look as so:

```
RECTYPE  TYPEDESC               PAGE    DOCIMGLINK 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
D        Delayed Birth Record   00127   1910-007704118500089870170008786670
D        Birth Record           00056   1910-007701897300089870160008810074
D        Delayed Birth Record   00118   1912-007704116600089870180008786651
D        Birth Record           00004   1913-007702338100089870200008804037
D        Birth Record           00249   1913-007702362500089870210008804281
```

I then have a table `DM_CONTENT` with the following information:

```
DM_ID   DM_PATH
------------------------------------------------------------
1       BR\1910\1910-007704118500089870170008786670.TIF
2       BR\1910\1910-007701897300089870160008810074.TIF
3       BR\1912\1912-007704116600089870180008786651.TIF
4       BR\1913\1913-007702338100089870200008804037.TIF
5       BR\1913\1913-007702362500089870210008804281.TIF
```

As you can see, `DM_PATH` is the `DOCIMGLINK` with additional information embedded. I wanted to use the `DOCIMGLINK` as a unique identifier to `JOIN` the two tables and bring back all the information. I thought, let's just parse out the part I'm trying to compare and that should do the trick.

```
SELECT
   D.RECTYPE
   ,D.TYPEDESC
   ,D.PAGE
   ,D.DOCIMGLINK
   ,DMC.DM_ID
   ,DMC.DM_PATH
FROM
   DOCUMENT D
   LEFT JOIN DM_CONTENT DMC
      ON D.DOCIMGLINK = PARSENAME(REPLACE(DMC.DM_PATH, '\', '.'), 2)
```

No results... odd, that should work but it doesn't. My solution instead was to use a CTE with the same exact `PARSENAME` function:

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT
   DM_ID
   ,PARSENAME(REPLACE(DM_PATH, '\', '.'), 2) AS 'DM_PATH'
FROM
   DM_CONTENT)
SELECT
      D.RECTYPE
      ,D.TYPEDESC
      ,D.PAGE
      ,D.DOCIMGLINK
      ,CTE.DM_ID
      ,CTE.DM_PATH
   FROM
      DOCUMENT D
      LEFT JOIN CTE
         ON D.DOCIMGLINK = CTE.DM_PATH
```

Brings back positive results! While I have this working solution, I want to understand *why* I can't do it the other way. There has to be something simple I am missing and it's driving me mad. Thanks in advance for assisting my ignorant filled brain fart!

Comment: I'd like to see the results of DM_Content using parse name... So use a subselect `LEFT JOIN (SELECT DM_ID, DM_PATH, D.DOCIMGLINK = PARSENAME(REPLACE(DMC.DM_PATH, '\', '.'), 2) as DOCIMGLINK FROM DM_CONTENT) DMC`  Run the select independent of the rest and see if you're getting the results you expect on the join.  you may consider making it a full outer join instead... so you see both sides while troubleshooting.

Comment: Not reproducible, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0f36/1

Comment: @xQbert The results of just the PARSENAME are a stripped link (no directory or image type information.) It looks identical to DOCUMENT.DOCIMGLINK

Comment: @ShannonSeverance This is very interesting - the SQL fiddle does indeed work appropriately, but in practice on this database (SQL 2012), it fails to work appropriately. I copied and pasted the exact statements above to ensure I did not change anything up, and my results were still negative. Weird.

Comment: A reach but you may have spaces at the end.   Try adding an rtrim( )

Comment: If not `trim`, perhaps  compare `length` as maybe it's not a space but a non-display character?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is the same code??? Your posted example works fine...well once I turned into something consumable.

```
create table #Document
(
    RECTYPE char(1)
    , TYPEDESC varchar(50)
    , PAGE varchar(10)
    , DOCIMGLINK varchar(50)
)

insert #Document
select 'D', 'Delayed Birth Record', 00127, '1910-007704118500089870170008786670' union all
select 'D', 'Birth RecorD', 00056, '1910-007701897300089870160008810074' union all
select 'D', 'Delayed Birth Record', 00118, '1912-007704116600089870180008786651' union all
select 'D', 'Birth RecorD', 00004, '1913-007702338100089870200008804037' union all
select 'D', 'Birth RecorD', 00249, '1913-007702362500089870210008804281'

create table #DM_CONTENT
(
    DM_ID int
    , DM_PATH varchar(100)
)

insert #DM_CONTENT
select 1, 'BR\1910\1910-007704118500089870170008786670.TIF' union all
select 2, 'BR\1910\1910-007701897300089870160008810074.TIF' union all
select 3, 'BR\1912\1912-007704116600089870180008786651.TIF' union all
select 4, 'BR\1913\1913-007702338100089870200008804037.TIF' union all
select 5, 'BR\1913\1913-007702362500089870210008804281.TIF'

SELECT
   D.RECTYPE
   ,D.TYPEDESC
   ,D.PAGE
   ,D.DOCIMGLINK
   ,DMC.DM_ID
   ,DMC.DM_PATH
FROM
   #DOCUMENT D
   LEFT JOIN #DM_CONTENT DMC
      ON D.DOCIMGLINK = PARSENAME(REPLACE(DMC.DM_PATH, '\', '.'), 2)

drop table #DM_CONTENT
drop table #Document
```

Comment: Positive - I just copied and pasted both of my above examples that I provided and the CTE works correctly, while the JOIN does not. I find it most curious - both are VARCHAR columns. This is a SQL 2012 environment.

Comment: I just tried this including your example on 2005, 2008r2, 2012 and 2014. All work exactly the same and returns rows for both queries. And two of those are even case sensitive databases. There is something going on with your code or the data is slightly different than what you posted. I couldn't being to tell you what it is but there is nothing in the code that would do that.

Comment: I appreciate the help - I'll look for anomalies in my data that might be causing for this issue.